# Axios Update error. Need to change the content

Tags: reactjs, axios, updates, edit, put

```
updateGame(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const game = {
  id: this.state.games.id,
  name: this.state.games.name,
  price: this.state.games.price,
  category: this.state.games.category
 }
 axios.put('https://localhost:5001/games/', game)
 .then(res => console.log(res.data)) 
}
```

I have two functions called Update and Delete. Delete is done, but need help with Update so I can change the content. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUrHG.png)

Comment: If `this` is `undefined`, it's probably related to how you're passing this method to whatever's calling it, which is *not included in your question*. Give a [mcve] (or, better, delete this and read https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/3001761).

Comment: Can you add all your component code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of class. Try to bind context of `updateGame` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
   this.updateGame = this.updateGame.bind(this);
}
```

More information about [Handling Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in React